# How to do foreach query with also checking null case?

Tags: c#, foreach

Ok this is what i am doing right now but i wonder are there any better approach to do it?

```
            if (vrChildNode.SelectNodes("//href") != null)
                foreach (var vrNodes in vrChildNode.SelectNodes("//href"))
                {

                }
```

As you can see i am actually querying 2 times. First for null check and second for foreach.

If i do the way below it throws error if there is no nodes

```
                foreach (var vrNodes in vrChildNode.SelectNodes("//href"))
                {

                }
```

Thank you for answers

c# .net 4.5

Comment: This is why you should always use empty collections instead of `null` collections.

Comment: Use an if statement inside the foreach loops to detect if something is null

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an extension method to do the check and ensure the result is non-null:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
}
```

Then you can write:

```
foreach (var vrNodes in vrChildNode.SelectNodes("//href").EmptyIfNull())
{

}
```

Comment: @Dialecticus Because you shouldn't be using null collections/sequences in the first place.  You should be using empty ones.  The framework is generally quite good about that.

Comment: your answer is very logical but in that case this question comes to my mind. Why C# is not default behaving like this ? Why do we need to waste time to write extension method and why there is no such thing right now ?

Comment: Forgot about this solution. Way cleaner than any of my suggested ones. :-)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I'd guess it's defensive behavior. If you're trying to iterate a null reference it's usually a mistake.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG There may be certain circumstances in which someone would want to distinguish a `null` collection from an empty one.  Generally it would be because they want to make it abundantly clear that there is some sort of invalid state going on, and they *want* the exception to be thrown when using that value.  The problem is that that's just not the case here; this is an improper use of `null`, not that the language handles `null` improperly.

Comment: @Servy they can simply add default extension like you mentioned and people wouldn't waste time to write another extension or search for like i am doing :(. And i don't think so anybody would want to throw an exception. Because it throws exception if you don't make null check. And it results in crash if you don't handle it.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG Exactly, *as it should*.  You wouldn't *want* to have it not throw an exception when in such a state.  As for the language providing such a method, I simply don't see it being something so useful as to warrant creating it, and is so easy to write that those people who *do* need it can create it easily enough.

Comment: It probably hasn't been added to the .NET library for the same reason no extension method for `string.IsNullOrEmpty` exists: calling an extension method on a `null` value can be confusing, because you typically expect that a `null` can't have anything called on it. So for now, just write it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The best and clearest way is to store it in a variable:

```
var nodes = vrChildNodes.SelectNodes("//href");
if (nodes != null)
    foreach (var vrNodes in nodes)
    {
    }
```

A less clean and less obvious way, but a single liner:

```
foreach (var vrNodes in vrChildNodes.SelectNodes("//href") ?? Enumerable.Empty<nodeType>)
{
}
```

I'd really suggest you to do the first. Everyone will see what you meant with a single look. With the second approach, you really first have to look and think about what the purpose is (I think it is already horrible result that SelectNodes **can** return null, but I know that's not in your hand).

If you like you can also create an extension method to do a check for you:

```
public static IEnumerable<nodeType> SelectNodesSafe(this typeOfvrChildNodes t, string selector)
{
    var res = t.SelectNodes(selector);
    if (res == null)
        return Enumerable.Empty<nodeType>();
    else // Redundant else
        return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var vrNodes in vrChildNode.SelectNodes("//href") ?? Enumerable.Empty<type>)
{
}
```